# Maya Python, can't access file icons

Tags: python, 3d, maya

Im trying to get the "hsFileMayaMB.png" to load into my fileBrowser script but Maya can't find it.

When I type

```
icon = "hsFileMayaMB.png"
```

and take that as an image path it shows nothing.

When I type the full path e.g. (on MacOs)

```
"/Applications/Autodesk/maya2018/Maya.app/Contents/icons/hsFileMayaMB.png"
```

everything works fine.

I know that you can access Maya icons like this:

```
icon = ":/cube.png"
```

But I don't know why it's not working with the above mentioned.
I also looked at

```
getenv "XBMLANGPATH"
```

but the Icon path is already in there.

Thanks for anybody looking into it.

Comment: Do you have anything funky in your project settings?

Comment: Hey, no nothing important. Just an extra sys path but I don't even load it with the userSetup.mel.